HDMI Output can’t display full HD resolution ON external monitor
I have a Dell Latitude 7320 laptop and want to extend the screen to my AIO PC Dell OptiPlex 7470 but in the PC it won't go full HD, just at 1366x720.
I've been use docking port to connect the HDMI cable to my laptop's USB type C port but it still does nothing.
I tried to connect to my friend's HP AIO PC and can go full HD, and my friend's laptop that also has the same brand and type with me can go full HD in my Dell AIO PC.
My system (Windows 11) is already up to date. Any solution for this will be very helpful.

There was no Dell Latitude 7020. Correct it, please? As far as the problem - you tested them with both another external screen and USB-to-HDMI with another laptop, but were you using all the same components, including cables? If yes, then it's possible your laptop, for some reason, doesn't detect the Dell AiO, using generic PnP panel driver, which has default 1366x768 resolution. Did you look in Device manager and did you try and change the resolution and/or refresh rate? This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/277407/cannot-change-the-rsolution-on-my-2nd-monitor

I'm sorry. I mean latitude 7320.
And how to change the resolution in device manager?

Have you checked the link I posted in my previous comment? There are a lot of screenshots and detailed instructions to do all the checks.

I've been trying all the instruction but one, reinstall the driver. I am confused which driver should i reinstall, is it the laptop's or the PC's

1/2 Definitely the laptop. The issue you're having is that laptop doesn't, in all probability, recognize the PC  as anything other than generic panel. Since every component you have has been tested with other, known to be working, equipment, then the only issue left is software, and the only one of these is to reinstall driver for the PC monitor as detected by Laptop. From my experience, this kind of issue happens ONLY when laptop has Discrete GPU ONLY and that GPU has failed. Since you said you confirmed other configs are working no point to recommend replacing HDMI cable, for example...

2/2... This goes to both direct HDMI connection from laptop HDMI port and from USB-C dock's HDMI. The only difference is that USB-C dock uses hardware adapter to convert USB-C (which is basically DisplayPort) to HDMI, but since you said it works with other laptop and your PC fine, it is ok. I have Latitude 7420 and it's working as it should with both HDMI-HDMI cable and USB-C dock with HDMI port. The other possibility is that you already have connected external monitors to your laptop and your Dell PC exceeeds the number and/or combined max resolution and refresh rate the laptop can support.
